# How to update only if a text value equals and specific text?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, where-clause

I need to update a row only if its param `status` equals `'CREATED'` to `'NEWSTATUS'`. I'm trying to do it with the following code, but it's still wrong.

```
UPDATE table t
SET t.otherId, t.status =
    CASE 
        WHEN (SELECT t.status FROM table t WHERE t.idRow) = 'CREATED' THEN '10', 'NEWSTATUS'
    END
WHERE t.idRow = 23
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you just looking for...:

```
UPDATE table SET otherId = 10, status = 'NEWSTATUS' WHERE idRow = 23 AND status = 'CREATED'
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you just want a simple `UPDATE` with a `WHERE` clause.

```
UPDATE table
       SET status = 'NEWSTATUS'
       WHERE status = 'CREATED';
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a `CASE` expression for the assignment of `status`:

```
UPDATE table t
    SET t.otherId,
        t.status = (CASE WHEN t.status = 'CREATED' 
                         THEN '10' ELSE 'NEWSTATUS'
                    END)
    WHERE t.idRow = 23;
```